# How to design an inductor which consists of four separate windings in the same core?

Tags: inductor, electromagnetism, magnetics, simulink, magnetic-flux

I need to design an inductor such that there will be four separate windings at the input side (each input is coming from a different DC-DC converter) then these four windings are combined at the output. All these actions will occur in the same magnetic core.

"The different converters are interleaved but they have their own power source so they can be thought as independent at each other until the inductor. The inductor will be employed in the LC filter of the DC-DC converters.

I have attached the schema of the configuration and the voltages of each winding.

I have modeled it in Simulink by using the magnetic domain blocks (electro-magnetic converters and reluctance blocks) but can't be sure if it theoretically makes sense or not because the simulation gives different flux (for each winding flux) results at each run, although other currents or voltages on the simulation are same at each time.

My research on the web did not end up well so far. I would highly appreciate it if anyone can give an idea or show me a reference.

---

[image: inductor configuration]
*Figure 1: Inductor configuration*

---

[image: winding voltages]
*Figure 2: Winding voltages*

---

Comment: What is the inductor supposed to do in this circuit?

Comment: It sounds to me that you are designing a transformer.

Comment: Have you followed [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/powersys/ref/mutualinductance.html) to implement Generalized Mutual Inductance?

Comment: @BrianDrummond the inductor is employed as LC filter with the capacitor shown in the figure.

Comment: @Transistor No, it works as an inductor. I know that the windings will affect each other but mainly the inductor will filter positive square wave output.

Comment: @user391130 No, you are designing a transformer, because as you say, the windings affect each other. You can't have it both ways, you can't be a little bit pregnant for instance. A transformer is not what you want here. You need four separate inductors, one from each supply, because you need to isolate the voltages. You can use a common capacitor though. If you want to use a single ferrite block with four windings on it, then that's possible, but the windings will need to be in distinct isolated magnetic circuits so that you have only mechanical integration, not electromagnetic integration.

Comment: @Neil_UK So by saying mechanical integration, you mean a non-magnetic material that will block the magnetic interference between the windings right?

Comment: @user391130 That would work, but it's also possible to choose regions in a block of ferrite where some windings will not couple to other windings. There's little point in doing it unless you're making 100s of thousands of parts and want the cost savings. Just use four separate inductors.

Comment: @Neil_UK ok, thanks a lot for your attention.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you originally assume that you need 4 inductors on one core?

Comment: @user253751 I have four converters, I calculated and  simulated the single inductor and single-core configuration but the inductance is not enough and increasing the inductance may be a solution but first I wanted to have more compact solution

Answer (score 3):

If the intent is simply to provide smoothing on the incoming pulses, then you do NOT want coupling (transformer action) between each winding.

There is nothing to be gained from coupling the windings on a common core, and quite a lot to be lost (e.g. edges from one input creating spikes doubling the voltage on another; possibly destroying its driver).

Simply use 4 separate inductors, and common the output terminals. There are screened inductors available to further reduce mutual coupling if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already tried your advice (separate inductor ) and it did work I just wanted to try a more compact inductor in order to reduce the size of the board. But I suppose I will end up doing separate cores structure.

Answer (score 0):

if you connect all the windings together at the non-dot end then  you may as well have just used a single inductor because all the windings are coupled magnetically.

Comment: I recommend you spend some more sentences to elaborate your reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are implementing a **multi phase coupled inductor** buck converter. This search term could set you back months or years, researching for the many ways it can be done, optimised and tuned.

I have seen research papers dated back to 2001 regarding them, and they are still an active research area within converters. They seem to be 99% concentrated on the opposing flux version. Main features of this setup are:

- No change in capacitor ripples compared to your non coupled version
- Individual inductor current ripples can be highly reduced, depending on duty cycle and coupling factor.
- Above could be traded for smaller inductance => Less turns => High efficiency => Faster step response.
- If fast step response is required, like in a cpu supply, output capacitance could be decreased. This as you get an effective transient ripple = steady state ripple/N-phases.
- Opposing flux will much reduce core flux, resulting in less air gap, which could result in less turns again for the same inductance.

A downside is that if duty cycle goes above 1/N-phases, you will need a lot leakage inductance, as delta flux (in other words inductance) is otherwise completely cancelled.

Another downside is the core material is effectively handled with N-phases times the switching frequency. So peak B field must decrease to keep the same core losses.

Below are some examples of implementations
[image: Example 4 phase coupled inductor]
[image: Another Example of 4 phase coupled inductor]

And a link to a [maxim article](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/tutorials/5/5997.html) to get you started.

Comment: thanks a lot for this detailed explanation. I will have more researches about this. 
And also I think another downside of this is the increase in the frequency also increases the skin effect, so thinner wire might have to be used and in order to have the same current parallel wire also should be used. Therefore the core bobbin window area might be a problem. It is just a brief idea that came to my mind. I don't know it is correct or not.

Comment: @user391130 yes you are correct. The multiplied frequency increases skin effect. But you are implementing a dc reactor, and not an ac transformer. As such skin effect should be proportional only to ac ripples component, and not base dc current.